# FindByName works for the first entry, but returns null for the second...?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, f#, xamarin.forms

I'm really confused about this behaviour of Xamarin.Forms. I have this Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GW.Frontend.XF"
             x:Class="GW.Frontend.XF.AppPage">
    <StackLayout x:Name="mainLayout" Padding="20,20,20,20">
        <Label Text="Welcome to GW" x:Name="welcomeLabel"
               VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Entry x:Name="passphraseEntry" IsPassword="true"
               Placeholder="Input your new pass-phrase:"
               TextChanged="OnPassphraseTextChanged" />
        <Entry x:Name="passphraseEntryConfirmation" IsPassword="true"
               Placeholder="Repeat your passphrase here"
               TextChanged="OnPassphraseTextChanged" />
        <Button x:Name="createButton"
                Text="Create my accounts" IsEnabled="false"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Clicked="OnCreateButtonClicked" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And this is the code in AppPage.xaml.fs:

```
namespace GW.Frontend.XF

open System

open Xamarin.Forms
open Xamarin.Forms.Xaml

type AppPage() =
    inherit ContentPage()
    let _ = base.LoadFromXaml(typeof<AppPage>)
    let mainLayout = base.FindByName<StackLayout>("mainLayout")
    let passphrase = mainLayout.FindByName<Entry>("passphraseEntry")
    let passphraseConfirmation = mainLayout.FindByName<Entry>("passphraseEntryConfirmation")
    let createButton = mainLayout.FindByName<Button>("createButton")

    member this.OnCreateButtonClicked(sender: Object, args: EventArgs) =
        ()

    member this.OnPassphraseTextChanged(sender: Object, args: EventArgs) =
        Console.WriteLine("______________________A")
        if (passphrase.Text.Length > 0) then

            Console.WriteLine("______________________B")
            if (passphraseConfirmation.Text.Length > 0) then

                Console.WriteLine("______________________C")
                createButton.IsEnabled <- true
```

Surprisingly enough, passphrase is not null (because ___B is printed in the console) but passphraseConfirmation is null! (So it throws a NullReferenceException.) How can this be? I'd expect `FindByName` work in all cases, not only for the first element in the StackLayout container.

Answer (score 1):

My bad, it's not that `passphraseConfirmation` was null, it's that its `Text` property was! (Apparently because if it's not set in the XAML and the user has not inputted anything on it yet, maybe it's still kept as null.)

I'll leave the question instead of deleting it, just in case someone overlooks this silly assumption from the way the Entry widget works.